# How do I call function(void) in gdb

Tags: c++, c, gdb, void, function-call

I am a complete beginner to reverse engg.
In recent times I have been going through gdb and how to debug the programss.

I have a big doubt bear me if it is a simple one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int flag(void){
    puts("okay you got this");
}

int main(void){
    puts("nope try again");
}
```

So i compiled this this program successfully, When I try run this program it gives me main function output

```
nope try again
```

so now how do i call the flag function to give the "okay you got this" output in gdb **I tried my best evrything and surfed blogs to get the answer but i endded up in failure** Hope ill get the solution and kindly suggest me what am I missing and what i needed to know on how does this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how to call `flag()` and skip the `puts` in `main`?, in this case:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
(gdb) print flag()
okay you got this
(gdb) break 10
(gdb) jump 10
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: No it doesn't give me the out either, If i give `p flag() ` gdb returns this `flag has no return type; cast the call to its declared return type` and if i give `p flag(void)` gdb returns `$1= {<text variable, no debug info>} [addrss] <flag>` so I am not able call that puts

Comment: _flag has no return type_: It is gcc (a warning) who tells you that (not gdb) use `void flag(void)` to fix the warning, and "no debug info" means that you are not compiling with `-g`, that is, symbols are deleted (and in consequence they are not callable), compile using: `gcc -g -o program program.c`

Comment: yeahh gotchaaa thank for the helppp !!! it returned the flag function output..

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. You just have to use break-point and jump commands:

1. Run your file with gdb: `gdb ./<filename>, or ./<python_file> dbg`
2. Set break-point: `break main`
3. Run the program: `run`
4. Use jump command to call any random function: `jump <function_name>` (In your case, the command will be `jump flag`)

Answer (score -2):

The function `flag` is not called and it is very likeley that it will not be present in the executable as not needed

It is called the dead code elimination

Comment: Nops, OP is debugging and for sure using  `-g` flag without optimization, there is not dead code elimination for `flag()` in such case.

Comment: @DavidRanieri `-g` does not guarantee no dead code elimintaion, more important is what is (if we consider the gcc in the default specs file). I use -g and have dead code eleiminated.

Comment: _I use -g and have dead code eleiminated._ in this case? I don't think so ... which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Only static functions can be dead code. Functions with external linkage might be invoked by other translation units including  those loaded dynamically.

Comment: @rici when you link executable functions in your code will not called "dynamically"

Comment: @DavidRanieri version does not matter, how do you build the gcc matters. You may set any options to be default. If you want to make sure that your dead code will be eliminated use:  `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections`

Comment: See [`dlsym`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

Comment: Of course version matters, `gcc` can not skip the entry (see rici's comment), in such case you are using a broken version of `gcc`, a tunned version of softonic or something like that :)

Comment: `--gc-sections`? come on ... you tell the linker to drop unused sections while debugging an unused function? ... don't look for the hair in the egg.

Comment: It's true that you can get `ld` to remove uncalled functions in a static build. That's not the default setting on any distro I know of, so it is unlikely to apply to OP.